# Need to fire function after animation completes - CAN NOT use timeout... Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to make the timing right on this animation, but am having an issue. The goal is to animate each slot at different speeds. Once the animation is completed, `console.log` *WIN* or *LOSE*. The problem is that the slots spin at a random speeds, so using a timeout wont be a consistent fix (sometimes animation will finish, and it delays too long before getting a *WIN*/*LOSE*.

I am trying to use the animate complete function (line 101 toward bottom), but I can't think through how I would pass a `running = true/false`. Obviously if I `return running` in the complete it will not be defined outside that function; and i cant run the function again.

When I look for similar issues, I keep finding `setTimeout` suggestions, which won't work here (unless you see a work around).

```js
//  ********************************************************
//  SLOT MACHINE ICONS. Each array has 3 icons for each slot 
//  ********************************************************

var array1 = [
  '<img data-id="0" src="imgs/temp-tea-1.png" alt="coffee pot icon">',
  '<img data-id="1" src="imgs/temp-coffee-1.png" alt="coffee pot icon">',
  '<img data-id="2" src="imgs/temp-espresso-1.png" alt="coffee pot icon">'
]
var array2 = [
  '<img data-id="0" src="imgs/temp-tea-1.png" alt="coffee pot icon">',
  '<img data-id="1" src="imgs/temp-coffee-1.png" alt="coffee pot icon">',
  '<img data-id="2" src="imgs/temp-espresso-1.png" alt="coffee pot icon">'
]
var array3 = [
  '<img data-id="0" src="imgs/temp-tea-1.png" alt="coffee pot icon">',
  '<img data-id="1" src="imgs/temp-coffee-1.png" alt="coffee pot icon">',
  '<img data-id="2" src="imgs/temp-espresso-1.png" alt="coffee pot icon">'
]


//  Generates random # between 0 and 2. Used for choosing winner and creating random slots
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

//  Generates winning array item between coffee, tea and espresso
function win(whatArray){
   var arrayItem = getRandomInt(0,2);
    var winItem = whatArray[arrayItem];
    return winItem;
}

//  Populates each slot with random icons to spin through
var makeList = function(whatArray, whatSlot){
 var slotArray = [];
  
 for(i=0; i < 100; i++){

    var randNum = getRandomInt(0,2);  // Generate random number
    var findItem = whatArray[randNum];  // Use random number to find associated array item
    var slot = whatSlot;  // Set which slot to append array item to (first, second or third)
    $('#' + slot).append('<div>'+findItem+'</div>');  // Append icon to HTML 
   }
   
  var winItem = win(whatArray);  // Generate winning icon for slot
  console.log("winner " + winItem);
  $('#' + slot).append('<div>'+winItem+'</div>');  // Append winning icon to end of list
}



//  Generate lists for each slot
makeList(array1, 'slot-1');
makeList(array2, 'slot-2');
makeList(array3, 'slot-3');

// Spin the slot and win some caffeine!
function Spin(){

 window.counter = 0;

 MoveSlots($('#slot1-wrapper'), 2500);
 MoveSlots($('#slot2-wrapper'), 5200);
 MoveSlots($('#slot3-wrapper'), 500);

 //var running = true;
 // console.log(running);

 var slot1attr = $('#slot1-wrapper div').children().last().attr('data-id');
 var slot2attr = $('#slot2-wrapper div').children().last().attr('data-id');
 var slot3attr = $('#slot3-wrapper div').children().last().attr('data-id');
 
 //var running = false;
 console.log('counter = ' + counter);

 // var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
  if(counter >= 3){
   if(slot1attr == slot2attr && slot1attr == slot3attr ){

    console.log("WIN");
   } else {
    console.log("LOSE");
    //$('.md-trigger').trigger('click');
   }
   // clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
 // }, 5500) 


function MoveSlots(el, speed){
 
 var time = speed;
 time += Math.round(Math.random()*10000);
 el.stop(true,true);

 var marginTop = -(100 * 150 ); //change 100 to height placeholder

 var running = true;

 el.animate(
  {"margin-top":marginTop+"px"},
  {
   'duration' : time, 
   'easing' : "easeInOutQuint",
   complete:function(){
    //do something! *********************************
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
   } 
  }); // end animate  

 } // end MoveSlots
} // end Spin
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I edited the code, and I actually got the global counter to "work", however, when the code checks to see if counter >=3, it is still animating so it still console's to 0.

Is there a way to loop this until the counter until the animation is done?

Comment: you need to have a global variable counter which will be incremented at each .animate({complete:func(){..cnt++..}})  so if counter is equal to counter it means all your  animation are done and you can move forward to print win or Lose

Comment: That's a good idea! thanks @AleksanderAzizi. I know this is a noob question, but how would i go about making the variable global? And what you are basically saying is that, the counter will be hit 3 times by each slot when makeList is fired... then after it equals 3 then run win/lose code? I love this idea, thank you so  much!

Comment: WHY DOES THIS HAPPEN?? ugh.  I thought the complete function is made for making sure code doesn't fire until all animations are done?  I have a console.log right after the makeList() to display counter... should show 3 if it waits for animations to finish, but it displays 0. For some reason makeList moves on in code before the counter is even finished executing... anyone out there understand jquery animation well and can help explain this? Maybe I should be trying something different, not complete
?